# How to simply check if servers PHP version is 5 or above?

Tags: php, validation

I'm creating a pre-installation checklist for a program. The program requires PHP5, so I need the checklist-script to check for PHP5's availability.
There is a function as `phpversion()`, that will return in the format of `5.3.6` or similar. However, I want the checklist to be very straight forward and simply tell you yes or no. So displaying the current version isn't helping me that much. Okay, one way is to use the `phpversion()` and remove the comas etc. But isn't there a neater way? (Weirdly enough, there is no information on this anywhere)

So, **How to simply check if servers PHP version is 5 or above?**

```
if (...) {
    echo 'Server has PHP5 or above!';
} else {
    echo 'Servers PHP version is lower then PHP5';
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a predefined constant:

```
echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION // displays 5
```

http://nl.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#reserved.constants.core

So:

```
if (defined('PHP_MAJOR_VERSION') && PHP_MAJOR_VERSION >= 5) 
{
  echo 'Server has PHP 5 or above!';
} 
else 
{
  echo 'Servers PHP version is lower then PHP5';
}
```

Above only works for PHP > 5.2.7, try this instead for lower versions:

```
if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.0.0') >= 0)
{
  echo '5 or higher';
}
else
{
  echo '4 or lower';
}
```

It is suggested in one of the comments here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php#91816

Comment: That would be great except: `Available since PHP 5.2.7.`

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly what I was looking for! I feel so embarrassed that I couldn't figure this out myself. I thought there must be some extremely weird function for this. Thanks!!

Comment: @timdev: You just killed my happiness.. Isnt there a similar function for lower versions of PHP?

Comment: Which is only available since version 5.2, so that won't do much good.

Comment: @Kalle - see my answer, you just use substr() on the return value of phpversion().  easy as pie.

Comment: @Kalle: check my edit for a more complete example for PHP < 5.2.7

Comment: Well, its getting very confusing, since most of these answers work. So I checked all the methods with `microtime()` and this method is giving me most stable (also lowest) results.

Comment: Alright, based on the performance results, this is the best solution. However, I replaced `phpversion()` with `PHP_VERSION`. Because that looks neater and seemed to make things 0.0000004 seconds faster. So thanks for the answer!

Comment: Know that checking performance in such extreme regions is very negligible.

Comment: @Luwe, yes agreed. However, in those cases you must do a little statistics on lowest and most stable result.

Answer (score 24):

Something like this you may be able to adapt:

```
<?php
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '6.0.0') >= 0) {
    echo 'I am at least PHP version 6.0.0, my version: ' . PHP_VERSION . "\n";
}

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0) {
    echo 'I am at least PHP version 5.3.0, my version: ' . PHP_VERSION . "\n";
}

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.0.0', '>=')) {
    echo 'I am using PHP 5, my version: ' . PHP_VERSION . "\n";
}

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.0.0', '<')) {
    echo 'I am using PHP 4, my version: ' . PHP_VERSION . "\n";
}
?>
```

You can see the [documentation here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php).

Comment: Good solution. Especially because PHP_VERSION is available while PHP_MAJOR_VERSION as mentioned by others, is only available since 5.2.

Comment: Yeah was going to suggest PHP_MAJOR_VERSION but I saw that little blurb in the documentation.

Answer (score 11):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php for an example:

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.0.0', '>=')) { ...
```

Comment: Yes, however is PHP_VERSION is not supported in PHP4, then it loses point..?!

Comment: If the installer really needs to work on PHP < 4.1, you can check to make sure version_compare exists first. `if (function_exists('version_compare') && version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.0.0', '>=')))`. That should work back to 4.0.

Answer (score 4):

If the function phpversion() is returning it just as a straight number, you could do:

```
if ( phpversion() >=5 ) {
    echo 'Server has PHP5 or above!';
} else {
    echo 'Servers PHP version is lower then PHP5';
}
```

Comment: It doesn't return a number but a string, containing the full version.

Comment: Amm, weirdly enough this works. Wow, can the answer be really that simple?

Comment: @GolezTrol: Thats what my first thought was, but technically it is just a number with decimals..

Comment: It does work because they are compared as strings. It will fail once we reach version 10. :) It is not a number. It contains two dots and cannot be converted to a float.

Comment: For the record: `phpversion()` does return as a string, there for it can be converted into number with `number_format()`. However, it is slower then the accepted method.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
```

You can have further information in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php). This is available in PHP4 and over.

Comment: that doesn't really answer his question, which seems to be something like "how can I tell if the output of phpversion() is aversion greater-than-or-equal-to 5.0

Comment: well if he cannot do a IF with the phpversion() number we have a problem ... kinda basic no?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( substr(phpversion(),0,1) >= 5) {
  //php >= 5
}else{
  //php < 5
}
```

That wasn't so hard, was it?

EDIT: If we're worried about version 10 breaking the above code:

```
if ( strtok(phpversion(),'.') >= 5) {
    // php >= 5
}else{
    // php < 5
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that will work once we reach version 10. :) Better search for the dot. I know PHP development isn't very fast, but I thought that of FireFox too, and now they've release 3 versions in a year.

Answer (score 1):

```
$version = explode('.', phpversion());
$major = (int)$version[0];
$minor = (int)$version[1];
$release = (int)$version[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Symfony2 already includes such a script. It's in `app/check.php`. It checks for a minimum of PHP 5.3.2 and also a lot of other things.

I suggest you just use that.

Answer (score 0):

`echo PHP_VERSION_ID;

//You use version 5.3.7 the output like 50307`

or echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION.PHP_MINOR_VERSION.PHP_RELEASE_VERSION; 
//You use version 5.3.7 the output like 537

Comment: The point of the version check was to eliminate servers, that are outdated. If and `PHP_VERSION_ID` is since 5.2.7. version. So if the php is version 4... then there will be an error.

Comment: Also it appears that PHP_VERSION_ID has to be predefined in your code, it wont come from the serverside http://ee1.php.net/phpversion