# Get the PHP version number only

Tags: php, server

I've been using this...

```
echo PHP_VERSION;
```

...to display the version of PHP running on the server, which usually displays something like...

```
5.4.6.1
```

But I've just discovered that on some servers I get more than the version number, and instead this gets displayed:

```
5.4.6.1ububtu1.8
```

Is there a way I can get just the numbers?

The reason being is I need to check the version of PHP and display a message, something like...

```
$phpversion = PHP_VERSION;
if($phpversion >= "5.5") {
    echo "All good";
} else {
    echo "Your version of PHP is too old";
}
```

...but of course if $phpversion contains anything other than numbers then this script won't work properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its never a bad idea to [check that manual](http://php.net/phpversion)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simply check if servers PHP version is 5 or above?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197290/how-to-simply-check-if-servers-php-version-is-5-or-above)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get full version (5.4.6.1)

```
  <?php
    preg_match("#^\d+(\.\d+)*#", PHP_VERSION, $match);
    echo $match[0];
```

It will return 5.4.6.1 in your example

To get version as you need (5.4)

```
preg_match("#^\d.\d#", "5.4.6.1ububtu1.8", $match);
echo $match[0];
```

It will return 5.4 in your example

[Test here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6606bc5672a6c41ec4c0ab7e33201b31fa479aff)

Comment: This regex can't handle multiple digits in each subversion. And, it even fails with the given example: numerically, `5.4.6.1ububtu1.8` should be `5.4.6.1`, but your regex yields `5.4.6`. A better pattern would be `^\d+(\.\d+)*`, or perhaps even just `^[0-9.]+`.

Comment: Yes, I have provided this regex to display only 3 digits  because he only need the two first to compare php version :)

Comment: He needs the first three _numbers_, not the first three _digits_. For example, feed “5.4.20” into your regex – it will spit out “5.4.2”.

Answer (score 7):

Taken from an example in the docs ([here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php#112131)):

```
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.5.0', '>=')) {
    echo "All good";
} else {
    echo "Your version of PHP is too old";
}
```

Test script:

```
 <?php

 echo PHP_VERSION;
 echo PHP_EOL;
 echo phpversion();
 echo PHP_EOL;
 echo version_compare(phpversion(), '5.5.0', '>=') ?: "false";
 echo PHP_EOL;
 echo version_compare(phpversion(), '5.6.0', '>=') ?: "false";
 echo PHP_EOL;
 echo version_compare(phpversion(), '5.7.0', '>=') ?: "false";
 echo PHP_EOL;
 echo version_compare('5.4.6.1ububtu1.8', '5.4.0', '>=') ?: "false";
 echo PHP_EOL;
 echo version_compare('5.4.6.1ububtu1.8', '5.5.0', '>=') ?: "false";
 ?>
```

Output:

```
$ php test.php
5.6.4-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
5.6.4-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
1
1
false
1
false
```

Comment: Although for "5.5.0ubuntu" it will return too old.

Comment: Try echo version_compare('5.4.6.1ububtu1.8', '5.4.6.1', '>=') ?: "false";

Comment: 5.4.6.1 isn't a semantic version, so of course it's not going to work. Version are <major>.<minor>.<patch>, so with the extra '.1' it becomes meaningless in the eyes of `version_compare` because it's not a valid version number.

Comment: Okay tell that to the OP since that's the format he reports.  verson_compare has handling of "extras".  That's the question he is asking, doing comparison based on string comparison when there are extras at the end. It's a very easy trap to fall into when version is crucial and you don't know if the OS is appending a string.

Comment: But 5.4.6.1 isn't a valid semantic version number (not that it has to be). And he posted that as an example of the output from `PHP_VERSION`, which isn't what he's asking about. He's asking how to know if the version is greater than 5.5, which my answer addresses. And just to cover the bases, `echo version_compare('5.4.6.1', '5.4.0', '>=') ?: "false";` prints 1.

Answer (score 4):

PHP provides a convenient function, [`version_compare`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php), for comparing [SemVer](http://semver.org/)-like version numbers. While you could do a whole bunch of manual string wrangling, I suspect in your use case you can make your life much easier by taking advantage of what comes in the box.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue some days ago, I found this snippet from PHP Docs

```
// PHP_VERSION_ID is available as of PHP 5.2.7, if our 
// version is lower than that, then emulate it
if (!defined('PHP_VERSION_ID')) {
    $version = explode('.', PHP_VERSION);

    define('PHP_VERSION_ID', ($version[0] * 10000 + $version[1] * 100 + $version[2]));
}
```

Now, `PHP_VERSION_ID` constant contains, what you want.

Link [here](http://php.net/phpversion)

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure that you are always at or above 5.2.7.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#reserved.constants.core

```
$phpversionmajor = PHP_VERSION_MAJOR;
$phpversionmajor = PHP_VERSION_MINOR;
if($phpversionmajor >= 5 && $phpversionminor >= 5) {
    echo "All good";
} else {
    echo "Your version of PHP is too old";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
echo filter_var(PHP_VERSION, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,
FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
```

The second Parameter will sanitize the results according to a `FLOAT` representation and third parameter allows fractions like a 'DOT'

Yo would want to take a loot at the **[PHP Manual- Sanitizing Filers](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's variable mangling capabilities to check for a specific version:

```
<?php
$v=PHP_VERSION;
echo "RAW: ".$v.PHP_EOL;

$n=$v+0;
echo "MANGLED: ".$n.PHP_EOL;

echo "CONSTANT DIRECTLY  MANGLED: ".(PHP_VERSION+0).PHP_EOL;

$u="5.4.6.1ububtu1.8";

echo "From string: ".$u.PHP_EOL;
$nu=$u+0;
echo "From mangled string: ".$nu.PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
$: ~/test> php -f v.php 
RAW: 5.5.24
MANGLED: 5.5
CONSTANT DIRECTLY  MANGLED: 5.5
From string: 5.4.6.1ububtu1.8
From mangled string: 5.4
$: ~/test>
```